# The recycle bin on (shared, redirected My Pictures/My Videos) folder is corrupted

Tags: dfs, folder-redirection

I recently moved the target of folder redirection from a share to a DFS namespace share, ie from `\\SITE1FILESERVER\Share` to `\\DOMAIN\Share`. I seeded the DFS contents and accidently copied the recycle bin as well. Now, whenever users login they see an error message:

```
"The recycle bin on (shared, redirected My Pictures/My Videos) folder is corrupted..."
```

The funny thing is that I do not have the issue for Documents - only for Pictures/Videos - even though all three are redirected and I am pretty sure I accidently copied the Recycle Bin for the Documents as well.

Both Videos/Pictures are set to "follow" the Documents folder.

I do not get the issue when logged in as Administrator.

This happens on any attempt to access/refresh the Recycle Bin

Any clues on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with `Personal` and `Desktop` special folders redirected on Windows 7 workstation in Active Directory to a Samba 3.6 share on a CentOS Linux server.

Every time a user logged in or opened a Recycle Bin icon on a desktop he got multiple messages like "The Recycle Bin on H:\ is corrupted. do you want to empty the Recycle Bin for this drive?".

I have found a solution on some [blog post](http://blog.bigsmoke.us/2010/03/25/preventing-the-creation-of-recycle.bin-on-samba-shares-by-windows-7). I've added

```
veto files = /$RECYCLE.BIN/
```

to `[global]` section of `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

I think you can use [File Server Resource Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734227%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for similar [disallowing `$RECYCLE.BIN` on Windows Server](https://serverfault.com/q/550275/1806).

Comment: This worked like a charm on Ubuntu 16.04. My only question is, where in the [global] section should I put the veto line? Right now it's the first line in the section, but I'm sure there's a more natural emplacement for it.